# Test local html/javascript files on IOS on Simulator

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, web, ios-simulator

I want to test some responsive web pages using touch events on IOS simulator, is that possible ?  If yes how can i do it ?

Any recommendations are the most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/) to set up a webserver on your local box.  Then in the IOS simulator point safari to the local server.